# Bash : Search if strings in one file exist in a directory and run a command on it

Tags: bash

Im trying to iterate thru a large directory ( 500 files ). I need to look into each file and check if they contain a specific string. The string comes from a different file that I have which looks like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
...
```

Now finding out all the files which have any of the "users" in them is easy using :

`grep -wFf my_list /path/to/dir/*`

which gives me

```
/path/to/dir/file1:#user1    <-- the "users" are added as comments to the file
/path/to/dir/file2:#user1
/path/to/dir/file2:#user2
...
```

However at this point I want to run a set of other commands using the `/path/to/dir/file1` and "user" as arguments and Im not sure how to proceed with that.

Only way I can think of is reading all the users (~1600) in an array and then search for each of them in every file using a for loop and then run my commands when I find a match but it looks like thatll be very compute intensive. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you get? Doesn't `grep` put `:` between the filename and matching line?

Comment: @Barmar - I edited the question and put the right output in for the grep command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output to a `while read` loop to execute the other commands.

```
grep -wFf my_list /path/to/dir/* | while IFS=: read -r filename user; do
    # code that users $filename and $user
done
```